# How do I run a program at startup on Raspberry Pi AFTER the GUI has loaded?

Tags: java, variables, raspberry-pi, startup, display

Okay, so I have this simple java program:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        // do some things with the robot
    }
}
```

I want to run this program on my Raspberry Pi at startup so I've put it in a shell script which I've called at the end of the `/etc/rc.local` file. This is my shell script:

```
cd /home/pi/Desktop
java Program
```

Whenever my Raspberry Pi boots up, my program throws an exception saying `Can't connect to X11 window server using :'0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable` as soon as it tries to instantiate the Robot class. I later found out that this is because the GUI has not yet loaded when my program is being executed so I've put a delay in `rc.local`. These are the last lines in `rc.local`:

```
sleep 60s
sudo sh /home/pi/Desktop/launcher.sh &
exit 0
```

Although the program starts running after the GUI has loaded, it still throws out this exception. I've tried:

1. Using `.bashrc` instead of `rc.local`
2. Putting a delay inside my `launcher.sh` script before calling my actual program
3. Calling another shell script that had a delay at the beginning and then called `launcher.sh`

I had no success and have depleted all my ideas and don't know where else to search for the solution to this issue.

Comment: Have you tried the `~/.config/autostart/` variant (cerate a `myprogram.desktop` there)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Robert, eventually I've used the path ` ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` to run my program because the `autostart` directory was not present in the `.config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start an application when **GUI** starts, you should add **.desktop** file to the *autostart* directory.

So,  in `~/.config/autostart` directory, create `my_script.desktop` file (substitute *my_script* with whatever you want).

```
touch my_script.desktop
```

Edit it (`nano my_script.desktop`)  so it looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Name=put_name_here
Exec=type_command_to_run_here
Type=application
Terminal=true/false (true if you want it to run in terminal)
```

Comment: Thank you @masan. My `autostart` directory was not present in `.config` so I've added it manually and tried your suggestion. Unfortunately it still didn't work but think I might have wrongly typed my command to the `Exec` parameter. Anyway your reply lead me to another similar solution where I had to add my command at the end of this file: ` ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` in order to get it running after the GUI starts. Thanks again!